# Top Down Parsing - First and Follow

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

I have the following grammar on which I am trying to learn how to do first and follow. I think I have the FIRST correct. However, the FOLLOW is confusing due to the nonterminal C.

Here is the grammar:

```
S --> ABC
A --> a | Cb |ε 
B --> C | dA | ε
C --> e | f
```

For the FIRST:

```
First(S) = First(A)-{ε} + First(C) = { a,f, e, ε}
First(B) = First(C) = {d,e,f,ε}
```

For the FOLLOW:

```
Follow(S) = {ε}
Follow(A) = First(B)-{ε} + First(C) = {a,e,f}
Follow(B) = Follow(C) = Follow(S) = { $}
Follow(C) = Follow(B) = Follow(S) = {b, $}
```

I’m having issues since there are two C one in production A and B? 
Am I close to having this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the First already is wrong.

As A and B are optional, and C has a non-empty first:

```
First(S) = First(A) + First(B) + First(C) - {ε}
First(A) = {a} + First(C) + {ε}
First(B) = First(C) + {d, ε}
First(C) = {e, f}
```

=>

```
First(A) = {a, e, f, ε}
First(B) = {d, e, f, ε}
```

=>

```
First(S) = {a, d, e, f}
```

---

First when occurrence is followed by nt,
Follow of rule when at end.

```
Follow(S) = {$}
Follow(A) = First(B) - {ε} + Follow(B) = {d, e, f}
Follow(B) = First(C) = {e, f}
Follow(C) = Follow(S) + Follow(B) + {b} = {b, e, f, $}
```

*(I hope I got this right.)*

---

***In detail:***

```
Follow(S) = {$}            [Start rule]

Follow(A) = First(B) - {ε} [S --> A.BC]
          + First(C)       [S --> AB.C as B or First(B) contains ε]
          + Follow(B)      [B. --> C | dA. | ε]

Follow(B) = First(C)       [S --> AB.C as C does not contain ε stops]

Follow(C) = Follow(S)      [S. --> ABC.]
          + {b}            [A --> a | C.b |ε]
          + Follow(B)      [B. --> C. | dA | ε]
```

The dot on the LHS like X. --> ... results in Follow(S);

The dot on the RHS like ... --> ... .X ... results in First(X) - {ε}
While there is an ε-production for X, continue: ... --> ... X. ...

*Mind, that these are "my" rules, your book might use a slightly different algebra.*

Comment: Yes, because of production BC

Comment: I have one question: in Follow(C) = Follow(S) + {b} = {b, $} shouldnt we follow B? since B --> C | dA | ε ??  I dont think it changes anything.

Comment: C occurs thrice, at the end of the S rule, so Follow(S), followed by b, and at an end of the B rule, so Follow(B). _Edited my answer with your correction._

Comment: Would it be too much for you to construct a table for me so i can see how to do it? Im very confused on how to do it. i cant follow the books example.

Comment: yes first is clear. How would i construct a parse table? Could you be so kind as to show me? i cant find any good examples online or in my book! Its confusing.. =(

Comment: Sorry, but im not sure what the In detail: is doing! Im not sure what you are doing with the brackets and dots? Is that suppose to be a parse table? If so thats more confusing than my book =(

Comment: [...] is the explanation, the dot is the read position. Is this notation helpful? Right of the dot is the Follow of the left of the dot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering the following for the grammar. As the firsts are already answered correctly.

```
follow(S) = {$};
follow(A) = {$,d,e,f};
follow(B) = {$,e,f};
follow(C) = {$,b,e,f};
```

Reason for including '$' in follow of A, B and C is. If there is a production A ---> ABC in the grammar, where C is nullable then everything in Follow(A) will be Follow of(B).